# How can I use the select tag to render the first and last names from my redux store?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-redux

So I am building an app that is run by RoR on the backend and Rails/Redux on the frontend. It is a simple case manager app where a litigation gets profiled and it belongs to a lawyer who has its own profile. The component below updates the litigation object that is on the ruby back end. However, when a user will update the lawyer attached to that litigation, I want to render a list of the lawyers available on my ruby back end. I am using the useSelect hook to get access to all my lawyers but I am having trouble figuring out how to render them in a select form.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { updateLitigation, litigationUpdated } from '../store/litigations'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { Button, FormControl, FormGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

const EditLitigation = ({ litProfile}) =\> {

    const lawyers = useSelector((store) => store.lawyers.list)
    
    const lawyer = lawyers.map((law) => {
        return law.first_name, law.last_name})
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const [lit, setLit] = useState({
        caption: litProfile.caption,
        lawyer_id: litProfile.lawyer.id,
        id: litProfile.id,
        court: litProfile.court,
    })
    
    const handleChange = e => {
        setLit({...lit, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let litigations = {
            ...lit,
            id: litProfile.id
        }
        dispatch(updateLitigation(litigations))
    }

return (
\<div\>
\<Form.Label\>Lawyer: \</Form.Label\>
\<Form.Select
type=''
name='lawyer.id'
options={lawyer}
getoptionlabel={lawyer}
getOptionValue={({lawyer_id}) =\> lawyer_id }
defaultValue={lawyer}
placeholder='LawyerId'
onChange={console.log(lawyer}\>
\</Form.Select\>

        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormGroup>
        <Form.Label>Caption: </Form.Label>
        <FormControl
            type='text' name='caption' defaultValue={lit.caption} placeholder='Caption' onChange={e => {lit.caption = e.target.value;}}>
        </FormControl>
    
        <Form.Label>Court: </Form.Label>
        <FormControl
            type='text' name='court' defaultValue={lit.court} placeholder='Court' onChange={e => {lit.court = e.target.value;}}>
        </FormControl>
    
        <button type='submit'>Update</button>
        </FormGroup>
        </Form>
    </div>

)
}

export default connect(null, {litigationUpdated, updateLitigation})(EditLitigation)
```

My first issue being that I can't seem to map over and return first and last names in an array (first and last names are two different key value pairs) and I always seem to end up with just the last name in a long line. My lawyers variable contains all of my lawyers as each individual objects within an array but I cant seem to push out just their first and last name. I believe I need this to properly render the name of the selectable lawyer.

Secondly, I never seem to render anything when I check my page. Not even my console.log works when I try to use the select option so I am not sure how to make it render the list of lawyers from the redux store. Here is my lawyers log:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        first_name: "Marco",
        last_name: "Alonso",
        litigations: [
            {},
            {}
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        first_name: "Howard",
        last_name: "Schultz",
        litigations: [
            {}
        ]
    },
```

Ive tried looking at a few forums and stackoverflow questions but keep hitting brick walls. Anyone have an recommendations or guidance? Ive also found it hard to find documentation on it so if you know of a resource i should check out, please let me know. All Ive run into is how to make select tags with hard coded data options.